# Intensity of sequential spin measurments in QM

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, quantum-spin

The following is a question from Sakurai's book *Modern Quantum Mechanics*, 2nd edition, page 60:

> A beam of spin $\frac12$ atoms goes through a series of Stern-Gerlach-type measurements as follows:
>
> 1. The first measurement accepts $s_z=\hbar/2$ atoms and rejects $s_z=-\hbar/2$ atoms.
> 2. The second measurement accepts $s_n=\hbar/2$ atoms and rejects $s_n=-\hbar/2$ atoms, where $s_n$ is the eigenvalue of the operator $\mathbf S\cdot\hat{\mathbf n}$, with $\hat{\mathbf n}$ making an angle $\beta$ in the $xz$-plane with respect to the $z$-axis.
> 3. The third measurement accepts $-s_z=\hbar/2$ atoms and rejects $s_z=\hbar/2$ atoms.
>
> What is the intensity of the final  $s_z=-\hbar/2$ beam when the  $s_z=\hbar/2$ beam surviving the first measurement is normalized to unity? How must we orient the second measuring apparatus if we are to maximize the intensity of the final $s_z=-\hbar/2$ beam?

**Proposed Solution:**
I assume the *intensity* is defined as the probability amplitude squared of getting $s_z = -
\frac{\hbar}{2}$ in the final measurement. So you start with the state $| \psi \rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} | +
\rangle + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} | - \rangle$ before any measurements are made, you then project onto the eigenstates which correspond to the measurements you accept, hence you first project onto $| + \rangle \langle + |$ and then $| +; 
\hat{n} \rangle \langle +; 
\hat{n}|$ (taking $\alpha = 0$) and finally $|-\rangle \langle - |$, this process hence yields the intensity given by $$\bigg(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \langle +
| + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \langle - |\bigg)\bigg(|- \rangle \langle - |+; \hat{n} \rangle \langle +; \hat{n} | + \rangle \langle + |\bigg) \bigg(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} | +
\rangle + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} | - \rangle\bigg).$$

Apparently this is not correct, does anyone know where I went wrong?

Comment: Why are you looking for $\langle\psi|(|+\rangle\langle-|+;\hat n\rangle\langle +;\hat n|+\rangle\langle +|)|\psi\rangle$? Your beam is normalised after the first projection.

Comment: @Dalum Could you elaborate on what you mean? What should I be looking for?

Comment: As I see it, the problem says you should in fact ignore the first projection, and just assume that your state starts in $|+\rangle$, properly normalised.

Comment: @Dalum  What is the basic protocol for finding the probability density of this type of sequential measurement. I only know the case where we want to find the probability of say some measurement eigenvalue $a$ corresponding to some operator $\hat{A}$, we then project onto the eigenstate to get $\langle \psi|a\rangle \langle a | \psi \rangle$ which is the probability amplitude. But in this case we start with state $| + \rangle$ and we end with $| - \rangle$.

Comment: @Dalum What then is the protocol for the sequential measurements starting and ending with different states,  and does it follow from the postulates of QM as in the simple case I outlined above?

Comment: What are you referring to by $|+\rangle$ and $|-\rangle$ in your initial state $|\psi\rangle$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the notation you posted in the comments, $s_z |\pm\rangle = \pm\frac \hbar2 |\pm\rangle$ and $s_n |\pm,n\rangle = \pm \frac\hbar2|\pm,n\rangle$, then you have correctly summarized the effect of the experiment as the right-to-left application of the projectors
$$
|- \rangle \langle - |
\cdot
|+; \hat{n} \rangle \langle +; \hat{n} |
\cdot
| + \rangle \langle + |,
$$
where you want to maximize the norm of the wavefunction after it's been acted on by that operator.

On the other hand, I've got no idea you got the superposition $| \psi \rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} | + \rangle + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} | - \rangle$ from, but it's wrong; the text does not make any reference to the state of the system before it reaches the first magnet. If your thinking there was "take a state that's equally likely to be in $|+\rangle$ as it is in $|-\rangle$, then that's not how you describe it, because the state you wrote down is coherent and it doesn't appear up by magic. Why not write down, say, $| \psi \rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} |+\rangle - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} |-\rangle$ instead?

Thus, you don't know what the initial state is, but you *do* know that you want the norm after the first projector comes up to be one, or in other words, what you really want to maximize is
$$
p=\frac{\bigg\||- \rangle \langle - |\cdot|+; \hat{n} \rangle \langle +; \hat{n} |\cdot| + \rangle \langle + | \cdot |\psi\rangle\bigg\|^2}{\bigg\|| + \rangle \langle + | \cdot |\psi\rangle\bigg\|^2}.
$$
Now, this seems like it depends on what the initial state is, but it doesn't really (since the experiment doesn't, either) unless you happened to start with on $|\psi\rangle = |-\rangle$, in which case the experiment doesn't make sense. As such, you're free to take whatever arbitrary state you want, for convenience, so you can just start with $|\psi\rangle = |-+\rangle$ and be done with $|\psi\rangle$, in which case the calculation reduces to maximizing
$$
p=\bigg\||- \rangle \langle - |+; \hat{n} \rangle \langle +; \hat{n} | + \rangle \bigg\|^2
=\bigg| \langle - |+; \hat{n} \rangle \langle +; \hat{n} | + \rangle \bigg|^2
.
$$

Answer (score 0):

"The s_z=|+>  beam surviving the first measurement is normalized to unity". "What is the intensity of the final s_z=|-> beam"? You seem to start and end with superpositions from which I don't see where you get them from. But those won't matter anyway, since there is only one Stern-Gerlach device that really does something. The first one creates the particles and the last one annihilates them. What remains is an amplitudo

$\langle-|+;n\rangle\langle+;n|+\rangle$.

As for the intensity, you should take the squared norm of this amplitudo, as usual in QM

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you mind giving a basic explanation of what we are doing? So after the first measurement we are in the state $| \psi \rangle = | + 
\rangle$. And after the last we are in the state $\langle - |$. So are you saying that for this reason in order to find the probability amplitude we consider $$\langle - |(|-\rangle\langle-|+;n\rangle\langle+;n|+\rangle \langle+|)|+ \rangle?$$

Comment: @John that's what I meant indeed